# Varargs class method header conversion error

Tags: c++, delphi, header, variadic-functions

I have a C++ class that I am converting to Delphi that has a varargs member function like this:

```
class ICInterface {
    virtual void printf(const char* fmt, ...) = 0;
};
```

I have tried to do this to make equivalent Delphi code so I can call it from Delphi:

```
ICInterface = class
    procedure printf(fmt : PAnsiChar); varargs; cdecl; abstract; virtual;
end;
```

But when I Compile, it gives me the error:

```
[DCC Error] ICInterface.pas(9): E2169 Field definition not allowed after methods or properties
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what are you trying to do.

If you need Delphi analogue of C++ code

```
class ICInterface {
    virtual void printf(const char* fmt, ...) = 0;
};
```

it is

```
ICInterface = class
    procedure printf(fmt : PAnsiChar; const args: array of const); virtual; abstract; 
end;
```

but it is not binary compatible with C++ code.

If you have a DLL written in C++ which exports C++ classes, you can't use this DLL in Delphi directly.

Answer (score 3):

You've run into one of Delphi's quirks.  Method description tags can't go in just any order.  `Virtual` has to come before `abstract`, and I'm not sure about the other two.

Also, Delphi doesn't allow you to declare `varargs` methods.  The declaration is valid only for importing `varargs` routines from external DLLs.

Comment: So then it's impossible to correctly translate a C++ abstract class with a varargs method in it?

Comment: @John: If you're looking for an exact translation, yes.  But have a look at Delphi's `format`, `write` and `writeln`, which can replace `printf`, and without the security holes that `varargs` tends to bring to your app.

Comment: Like I said, this is an abstract class, so I'm writing functions in Delphi that will be passed pointers to C++ classes that are derived from the abstract class I'm translating. I really wish there was a way to do it :(

Comment: @John: See my comment from your other question. That's a very bad idea in general, and you're just asking to end up tripping over a handful of different kinds of undefined behavior.  You'd be much better off implementing COM interfaces, which do basically the same thing you're describing, but in a safe, well-defined way.

Comment: +1 C++ classes, in general, cannot be used across a compiler boundary. COM is one solution, but it is somewhat heavyweight. Writing and consuming COM interfaces is not too hard in Delphi, a little harder in C++ and rather painful in C! If you have got a small enough surface area to the interface, and you have control of the C++ code, you could export it as an extern "C" interface using free functions.